# How to add 2 variables into a WKInterfaceLabel

Tags: xcode, swift3, apple-watch

I would like to add a string and an integer into one WKInterfaceLabel on WatchKit.

The integer is working fine like this;

```
self.green.setText(String(greenSpaces))
```

How would I go about adding this string;

```
let greenStreet = "Green Street "
```

Into the label? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest using string interpolation:

```
self.green.setText("\(greenSpaces) Green Street")
```